# Django restframework: Validate a related field with a list of IDs

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

Given an endpoint `/cars`, I'd like to create a Car with a list of allowed parking locations.

```
request.user.parkings.all() # Mike owns 2 parking locations, with ids 3 and 5
```

If I POST to `/cars` with `{"parkings": [3,5,6], ...}` the API should return *400 bad request*, because I'm using a parking location (id: 6) that doesn't belong to me.

In [github](https://github.com/search?q=PrimaryKeyRelatedField%20many%3DTrue%20validate&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) nobody is seems to be writing validation logic for this. Without `validate_parkings(self, value)` I get status code 201.

Now the only way I came up to validate this was to iterate over the list `value` in the validation function, which means I hit the database:

```
def validate_parkings(self, value):
    # print type(value), value
    u = self.context['request'].user
    for p in value:
        if not p.owner == u:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("parking doesn't belong to you")
    return value
```

I expect more than 100 parkings occasionally. 100+ selects for just one validation smells very very bad.

- Why is nobody writing validations for this?
- Should I add this logic somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping you can try like:

```
def validate_parkings(self, value):
    user_parkings = set(self.context['request'].user.parkings.all())
    post_parkings = set(value)
    if not post_parkings.issubset(user_parkings):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("parking doesn't belong to you")
    return value
```

Comment: thanks! I checked it with a unit test `self.assertNumQueries(n, lambda: client.post(url, format='json', data=payload))`. It adds up correctly and does not make a query for each element.